# Load VectorDrawable from Assets

Tags: android, xml, assets

I have a few hundred vector drawables (converted from SVG) that I would like to load in my app, and I would like to not clutter up my Resources with them.  I have tried to put them into the assets, but an exception is thrown when trying to create the XML parser from the asset manager with AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser.  (I am assuming this is because the XML is uncompiled... the exception message only includes the path to the file).

Is there a way to compile these myself outside of the IDE?  Or better way to load vector art from assets?

Comment: is it possible than set vector drawable put in drawable folder

Comment: Yes, possible, but I would like to keep from cluttering up my resources with all these files.  It would also be very handy if I could list the files available in a directory instead of referring to them by their resource IDs.